# compile text files in raw folder in order to make it inaccessible

Tags: android, file, text, compilation, apk

Can I compile text files in **raw folder** to binary to encrypt it from being readable by other users?

Where should I put text files to compile binary in the **apk** file in order to be unavailable for the user to read?

I'v been putting many text file in `res/raw` folder as I do not want anyone to use my text files.

Some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can be compile text file in raw folder to binary?

I am assuming that by "compile", you mean "encrypt". You are welcome to encrypt files and put them in `res/raw/`. It will do you little good, as anyone who wants to will be able to decompile your app, get your encryption key, and decrypt the files.

> i do not like anyone to use my text files

They are not your files. They are the user's files, since it is the user's device. If the user wishes to access those files, the user will do so. If you do not want the files to be accessed that way, do not put them on the user's device in the first place.

Comment: thanks, yes my mean was encrypt. How can i encrypt my files? and how can i use them?